# Turned arduino 5vdc analog pin to 0vdc (gnd) in order to mimic a momentary switch

Tags: arduino

I'm just wondering how I would go about getting the normal 5vdc that comes out of the Arduino analog/digital pins to a 0vdc signal? I wanting to mimic a push button (momentary switch) so that it acts as if I am pushing a button on a remote.

I'm sure I could use a resister of some value in order to get it down to 0vdc but I am unsure of that value nor am I sure that's the *best* way to go about doing something like this.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

**update**

Would using a **[TLP592A](http://www.toshiba.com/taec/components2/Datasheet_Sync/200709/DST_TLP592A-TDE_EN_4499.pdf)** work doing it this way:

[image]

Comment: Just set an output pin low (logic 0)

Comment: @PeterBennett Just because you set the output to low doesn't mean it will be 0 vdc.

Comment: If you really want 0.0 volts, you'll have to drive a relay with an output pin, then the relay contacts will be the same as a switch connected to ground.

Comment: I agree with the above - use the nIO pin to drive a transistor that turns on or off a relay. The relay contact acts just like a momentary switch and is isolated from the relay coil.

Comment: I'd rather get away without needing to use a relay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What interface you will need depends on the circuit of the remote. If the switch shares a common ground with the Arduino then you might get away with just connecting directly to it. However for safety I would use a diode or transistor to provide an 'open collector' output. The circuit below shows how both a diode and transistor would be wired (choose one *or* the other, not both!).

[image]

Some remotes have their switches connected to battery positive, perhaps to make the transmitter turn on whenever a button is pressed. Others have buttons arranged in a matrix of rows and columns, so both ends of the switch may be floating. In these cases you can use an opto-coupler or PhotoMOS 'relay' (opto-coupler with FET output).

The circuit below shows how to use an opto-coupler. Note that the opto-coupler's output is polarity conscious, so you may have to swap pins 4 and 5 to get it working.

[image]

Comment: Please check my updated original post and see if I have this connected correctly.

Comment: Disconnect the wire going from pin 4 to Arduino Ground, and make a connection from pin 4 to pin 6. If it acts like the switch is permanently on then swap the wires going to the switch. And you need a resistor in series with pin 1 or 2 to limit current going through the LED.

Comment: Would a 330ohm resister work for pin 1 then?

Comment: Yes. A 330 Ohm resistor should set LED current to ~10mA.

Comment: Bruce, the +5V is the Arduino 5vdc pin, correct? And the 330ohms is connected to one of the digital pins on the Arduino, correct? And i also bought the 4N25 instead of the 4N37-will that work with this?

Comment: Yes. The 4N25 has a lower current transfer ratio, but it should work OK so long as it doesn't need to switch more than 2.5mA.

Comment: Doesn't look like it works as I am needing it to. However, I am using a 4.7k resister instead of the 330ohms.... I need one side to be **OFF** until I put the digital pin *HIGH*. Touching one side of the switch to ground turns on whatever that switch does. Currently, either HIGH or LOW acts as if the switch is being pressed. It should only be "pressed" when I take the digital pin **HIGH** and not pressed when its **LOW**.

Comment: To get the optocoupler to turn on only when the digital pin is HIGH, connect pin 2 to ground and pin 1 to the resistor. 4k7 should work if the switch has a weak pullup (10k or higher). Make sure that pin 6 is free (not connected to anything).

Comment: By *Pin 1 to resistor* do you mean with 5v->resistor->Pin 1?

Comment: The resistor is connected to an output pin from the Arduino (not +5V, which would cause the opto-coupler to be permanently turned on!)

Comment: Ah ok. Well connecting it like that doesnt seem to do anything on the other end (turning on the device.) In order to turn the device on, the button has to be held down for about 6 seconds. I have a timer to hold down more than that and i still do not see it turn on. I am using the 330 Ohms resistor.

Comment: So its:
-Android pin 8->330 ohm->chip pin1  |  
-Android gnd  ->chip pin2  |  
-Chip pin4->one side of switch  |  
-Chip pin5->other side of switch

Comment: im getting 4.58v on pin 1 using the 330 Ohms.

Comment: It should be about 1.1V. Either pin 2 is not connected to Arduino Ground, or the LED inside the opto-coupler is blown. What voltage do you read between pin and pin 2?

Comment: ok i put an LED between that and the chip pin and i am reading ~1.9v. But i am still now getting any output.

Comment: Between pins 1 and 2 of the opto-coupler? If so then it is fried.

Comment: Yep that must have been the reason. I replaced the 4th with a new one and now it works as it should. Thanks bruce!